# Exception " UT000004: getResponseChannel() has already been called" when i invoked the service using curl command

Tags: java, web-services, rest, curl, jboss

When am trying to invoke the rest service (Spring) deployed in jboss wildfly am getting following exception

18:33:00,767 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-9) Blocking request failed HttpServerExchange{ POST /webResults/tx/jurisdiction/SridharJurisdiction/election/election/processFile}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000004: getResponseChannel() has already been called
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpContinue.createResponseSender(HttpContinue.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler$ContinueConduit.read(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:104)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:181)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:1952)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:294) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:146)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.close(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:218)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.closeAndDrainRequest(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletBlockingHttpExchange.close(ServletBlockingHttpExchange.java:69)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.endExchange(HttpServerExchange.java:1404)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:193)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]

Please let me know your thoughts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue related to WildFly 8 and 9 and still open.

But a workround was found, dropping the header definition about Expect:100-continue in sender....

I hope this help you.

When I use Postman plugin to test my restful services I have no problem..
I think Postman dont send "Expection: 100-continue" and "keep-alive"..

I solve my problem using cURL in this way:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Expect:" -F facebookId=12313123123 http://localhost:8080/desafio-webapp/person/`

Track issue link:

[track 1](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242415)

[track 2](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3560)